# Grouped bar chart of multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

first of all: I'm completely new to python.

I'm trying to visualize some measured data. Each entry has a quadrant, number and sector. The original data lies in a .xlsx file. I've managed to use a `.pivot_table` to sort the data according to its sector. Due to overlapping, number and quadrant also have to be indexed. Now I want to plot it as a bar chart, where the bars are grouped by sector and the colors represent the quadrant.

But because number also has to be indexed, it shows up in the bar chart as a separate group. There should only be three groups, 0, i and a.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d = {'quadrant': ["0","0","0","0","0","0","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","II","II","II","II","II","II","II","II","II","II","II","II","III","III","III","III","III","III","III","III","III","III","III","III","IV","IV","IV","IV","IV","IV","IV","IV","IV","IV","IV","IV"], 'sector': [0,"0","0","0","0","0","a","a","a","a","a","a","i","i","i","i","i","i","a","a","a","a","a","a","i","i","i","i","i","i","a","a","a","a","a","a","i","i","i","i","i","i","a","a","a","a","a","a","i","i","i","i","i","i"], 'number': [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6], 'Rz_m': [67.90,44.17,44.30,63.43,49.87,39.33,61.17,69.37,66.20,44.20,64.77,39.93,44.33,50.97,55.90,51.33,58.23,44.53,50.03,47.40,58.67,71.57,57.60,70.77,63.93,47.37,46.90,34.73,41.27,48.23,58.30,47.07,50.53,51.20,32.67,50.37,37.50,55.50,41.20,48.07,56.80,49.77,40.87,44.43,44.00,60.03,63.73,72.80,51.60,45.53,60.27,71.00,59.63,48.70]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

B = df.pivot_table(index=['sector','number', 'quadrant'])

B.unstack().plot.bar(y='Rz_m')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data viz ecosystem in Python is pretty diverse and there are multiple libraries you can use to produce the same chart. Matplotlib is a very powerful library, but it's also quite low-level, meaning you often have to do a lot of preparatory work before getting to the chart, so usually you'll find people use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/) for static visualisations, especially if there is a scientific element to them (it has built-in support for things like error bars, etc.)

Out of the box, it has a lot of chart types to support exploratory data analysis and is built on top of matplotlib. For your example, if I understood it right, it would be as simple as:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.catplot(x="sector", y="Rz_m", hue="quadrant", data=df, ci=None,
                height=6, kind="bar", palette="muted")
```

And the output would look like this:
[image]

Note that in your example, you missed out "" for one of the zeroes and 0 and "0" are plotted as separate columns. If you're using seaborn, you don't need to pivot the data, just feed it the `df` as you've defined it.

For interactive visualisations (with tooltips, zoom, pan, etc.), you can also check out [bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html#standalone-examples).

There is an interesting wrinkle to this - how to center the nested bars on the label. By default the bars are drawn with center alignment which works fine for an odd number of columns. However, for an even number, you'd want them to be centered on the right [edge](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html). You can make a small alteration in the source code `categorical.py`, lines beginning 1642 like so:

```
# Draw the bars
offpos = barpos + self.hue_offsets[j]
barfunc(offpos, self.statistic[:, j], -self.nested_width,
        color=self.colors[j], align="edge",
        label=hue_level, **kws)
```

Save the `.png` and then change it back, but it's not ideal. Probably worth flagging up to the library maintainers.

Comment: Is there a way to shift all bars to the middle of the label?

Comment: I'v expanded the answer to cover this :)

Comment: second question: this shows only one bar for each quadrant. Is it possible to show every bar (sic in this case) and still have them colored according to their hue?

Comment: Do you mean x-axis should be "number"? And where would you want to plot sectors? If you want one plot per sector, you can loop over your data frame and subset it to a sector at a time, feeding the subset data frame to the catplot().